# Path Sum's Recursive Implementation Question

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I'm trying to do this question from leetcode(#113 Path Sums II).

> Given a binary tree and a sum, find all root-to-leaf paths where each path's sum equals the given target sum.

My approach:

This problem seems ripe for recursion. I start from the very top of the tree. Everytime I meet a non-leaf node, I recurse further into the tree while keeping track of the `current_path` I've taken and my `current_sum`. If I do meet a leaf node, I check if my `current_sum` is equal to the `target`. If it is, I add that path to the list of paths I want to return. Otherwise, we explore other paths.

```
def pathSum(self, root: TreeNode, target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    paths = [] #variable we return
    
    def dfs(node, current_sum = 0, current_path = []):
        if not node:
            return False #Edge case
        
        # Adding my current place
        current_path.append(node.val)
        current_sum += node.val
        
        if not node.left and not node.right: # Is this a leaf node?
            if current_sum == target: #Is the sum == target
                paths.append(current_path) #Add the current path
                
        else: #keep recursing since we are not at the leaf
            dfs(node.left, current_sum, current_path) 
            dfs(node.right, current_sum, current_path)
            
    dfs(root,0,[])
    return paths
```

However, for some reason my current_path variable is acting like a global variable... In my head, each time `dfs()` is called we create a separate `current_path` variable that gets passed to the `dfs()` functions we call later. However, when I actually run the code `current_path` keeps track of all the nodes I've visited.

The extremely odd thing is that even though `current_path` keeps track of what happened in the other recursive calls, `current_sum` does not. I've never had this problem with other recursive implementations though...

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're appending any `node.val` here in your `current_path` without any conditional statements:

```
current_path.append(node.val)
```

which'd probably cause an algorithm bug.

In Python, this'll pass through, similarly with a DFS:

```
class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, root, target):
        def depth_first_search(node, target, path, res):
            if not (node.left or node.right) and target == node.val:
                path.append(node.val)
                res.append(path)

            if node.left:
                depth_first_search(node.left, target - node.val, path + [node.val], res)

            if node.right:
                depth_first_search(node.right, target - node.val, path + [node.val], res)

        res = []
        if not root:
            return res

        depth_first_search(root, target, [], res)
        return res
```

Similarly in C++:

```
// The following block might trivially improve the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


#include <vector>

const static struct Solution {
        const static  std::vector<std::vector<int>> pathSum(
            const TreeNode* root, 
            const int sum
            ) {
            std::vector<std::vector<int>> paths;
            std::vector<int> path;

            depthFirstSearch(root, sum, path, paths);

            return paths;
        }

    private:
        const static void depthFirstSearch(
            const TreeNode* node,
            const int sum,
            std::vector<int>& path,
            std::vector<std::vector<int>>& paths
        ) {
            if (!node) {
                return;
            }

            path.emplace_back(node->val);

            if (!node->left && !node->right && sum == node->val) {
                paths.emplace_back(path);
            }

            depthFirstSearch(node->left, sum - node->val, path, paths);
            depthFirstSearch(node->right, sum - node->val, path, paths);
            path.pop_back();
        }
};
```

In Java, we'd use two LinkedLists:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final List<List<Integer>> pathSum(
        final TreeNode root, 
        final int sum
    ) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> tempRes = new LinkedList<>();
        pathSum(root, sum, tempRes, res);
        return res;
    }

    private static final void pathSum(
        final TreeNode node, 
        final int sum, 
        final List<Integer> tempRes, 
        final List<List<Integer>> res
    ) {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        tempRes.add(new Integer(node.val));

        if (node.left == null && node.right == null && sum == node.val) {
            res.add(new LinkedList(tempRes));
            tempRes.remove(tempRes.size() - 1);
            return;

        } else {
            pathSum(node.left, sum - node.val, tempRes, res);
            pathSum(node.right, sum - node.val, tempRes, res);
        }

        tempRes.remove(tempRes.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for taking the time to type that out! Your implementation seems to work and is much friendlier looking than my mess. But I'm still confused why just passing in current_path doesn't work. Is it that because a list is mutable, it'll retain what happened to it from recursion?

Comment: BigBear, mixing recursion (functional style) with side effects (imperative style) is a recipe for upset stomach. In my answer I avoid `append` mutation by using `[*path, node.val]`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider solving the problem using Python's powerful generators -

```py
def pathSum(root: TreeNode, target: int): -> List[List[int]]
  def dfs(node, path = []):
    if not node:
      yield path
    else:
      yield from dfs(node.left, [*path, node.val])
      yield from dfs(node.right, [*path, node.val])

  def filter():
    for path in dfs(root):
      if sum(path) == target:
        yield path

  return list(filter())
```

Separating concerns of `dfs` and `filter` makes this program easier to write. And generators give us linear *O(n)* performance.

---

Now that we know generators, a more natural version of this program might be -

```py
def pathSum(root: TreeNode, target: int): -> List[List[int]]
  def dfs(node, path = []):
    # ...

  def filter():
    # ...

  yield from filter() # <- generator
```

And better, since we're no longer returning a `list`, we can write the `for` loop directly -

```py
def pathSum(root: TreeNode, target: int):
  def dfs(node, path = []):
    if not node:
      yield path
    else:
      yield from dfs(node.left, [*path, node.val])
      yield from dfs(node.right, [*path, node.val])

  for path in dfs(root):
    if sum(path) == target:
      yield path               # <- pathSum can yield too!
```

You can step thru the answers using `for` -

```py
for answer in pathSum(root, target):
  print("solution found:", answer)

# ...
```

Or gather all of the answers in a `list` -

```py
answers = list(pathSum(root, target))
print(answers)
# [ ... ]
```

---

Did you notice that we can reduce memory use to half? Because `path` is not mutated, each `dfs` sub-process can share a memory reference -

```py
def pathSum(root: TreeNode, target: int):
  def dfs(node, path = []):
    if not node:
      yield path
    else:
      next_path = [*path, node.val]
      yield from dfs(node.left, next_path)  # shared
      yield from dfs(node.right, next_path) # shared

  for # ...
```

---

I hope you learned something fun about Python generators!